Qué significa "lo tienes a cappella"?
Oyendo la canción "Maldito alcohol" de Pitbull me encontré con la siguiente expresión:

Yo quiero ver si tú lo tienes a cappella

Bien.
Esa canción tiene muchas letras equivocadas en la internet, quizás es el caso acá, pues, en el video de la canción, se escucha claramente "capela" en vez de "capella".
A cappella es como un estilo musical y la sentencia no tiene mucho sentido para mi.
Me pregunto si esa frase existe o entonces que es dicho en la canción.
Otra versión encontrada en la internet dice así:

Yo quiero besitos los tienes a capellas

Pero creo que la primera es más correcta.

Sin entender las frases de la canción por completo, muchas veces he escuchado o leído en Chile una acepción de "a capela" como metáfora de no utilizar protección o profilaxis (una búsqueda en Google confirma la asociación).
Dados los temas habituales del reguetón y de esta canción en particular, puede suponerse que estas frases estén en ese ámbito de significación.

Partiendo que es Reguetón (aunque no es propio de este género) te diré que, principalmente en este género, no buscan un significado profundo de las frases, solo buscan algo que pegue en sonido y ritmo.

Mami yo te veo ahí con tus amigas
Y todas tan bien ricas y fuera de liga

Amigas rima con liga, y hasta tiene un poco de sentido, la cosa es que siempre buscan que rime.
Yo creo, que eso de "a Capellas" va por el lado del termino Italiano ("a cappella") que significa: La forma de crear música únicamente por medio de la voz humana.
Como quien dice, Pitbull (el cantante), pone a disposición de la damisela, su boca para darle muchos besos 
PD: Con el reguetón nunca se sabe... 
